# Woocommerce, products don't show up in "Shop" page (wordpress)

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, web

In the "shop" page of my Wordpress website, the categories of the products are shown, and the number of products for each category, but when I choose one category, the products don't show up. What may be causing the problem, where should I look for it?

(be kind, I'm sensitive :P )

Answer (score 0):

I fixed the problem, it was related to a plugin "qTranslate support for WooCommerce" which I deactivated because it was the problem. :)